# 404 Error on Forum Submit in a Subfolder of Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, forms, submit, http-status-code-404, subdirectory

I have an issue with a form throwing a 404 error on submission but only when certain words are in the body of the post.

Here is my form.

```
<form role="form"  action="edit-training-page.php?id=<?php echo $training_id; ?>" method="post" onSubmit="return confirm('Confirm Updating Training Page?');">
            <div class="form-group fl w300 mr">
                <label>Training Name</label>
                <input name="training_title" type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="" required value="<?php echo $training_title ; ?>">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group fl w200 mr">
                <label>Short URL</label>
                <input name="training_url" type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="" required value="<?php echo $training_url ; ?>">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group fl w100 mr">
                <label>Sort Order</label>
                <input name="training_order" type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="" required value="<?php echo $training_order ; ?>">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group fl mr" style="width:100%;">
            <textarea name="traininfo" rows="20" cols="80" /><?php echo $traininfo ; ?></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="clear mt " >
            <input type="hidden" name="training_id" value="<?php echo $training_id; ?>" />
            <button type="submit" name="update" class="btn btn-success fl mr"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i> Update Training Page</button>


        </form>
```

We have a sub-folder inside of WordPress for a dashboard system not related to WordPress. It is all php driven script. It is in a folder on the root of server, this form is for adding training content. I have been migrating training documentation from another location into this new system. It randomly throws a 404 on submission even though the URL is correct. For example today if the word "from" was in the textarea field it would give a wordpress 404 error screen on the submission. I have checked the reserved WordPress list in WordPress and none of the input fields are names that are reserved.

I tried excluding folder by editing the .htaccess file and changing the line to 
RewriteRule ./ /index.php [L] - No change.

The php code for processing the form is on the same page.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really an issue with WordPress. This is most likely due to the inclusion and configuration of [`mod_security`](http://www.modsecurity.org/) within Apache. So, you'll either need to modify the configuration, or just rid yourself of that particular module if you are able.

Try this in your .htaccess to turn it off:

For mod_security:

```
# Turn off mod_security filtering.
<IfModule mod_security.c>
  SecFilterEngine Off
</IfModule>
```

For mod_security2:

```
# Turn off mod_security filtering.
<IfModule mod_security2.c>
  SecRuleEngine Off
</IfModule
```

However, note that Apache may have been configured in such a way as to not allow turning it off in .htaccess.

Comment: Tried those both in the .htaccess in root folder, and it caused the wordpress side to not work at all. Tried it in the folder of the script and with mod_security.c and still gives issue, if mod_secruity2 is in the htaccess i cant access the folder at all

Comment: Then you are going to have to dig into your global apache configuration rather than using .htaccess. If you don't have access to that, then work with your hosting provider.

Comment: You should be able to use [mod_security's whitelisting feature](http://resources.infosecinstitute.com/avoiding-mod-security-false-positives-white-listing/).